# Which cms or script for social network wiki?

Tags: php, content-management-system, wiki, social-networking

I am building a social network. I need a cms that will allow users to contribute content. Each content item will need to have a google map, list of features, ratings, comments, etc.
And the content must be editable by other users with revision control.
Also, each user should have a profile with their bookmarked content items, contributed items, comments, etc.

It's very important that I can create a template for the wiki/content entries so that each item looks uniform. (and as a kick in the teeth, I would like to be able to search for wiki items using a radial search or map)

Joomla was my first choice, as I've used it for many projects, but the wiki functionality is not there.

I was also setting up a grou.ps site, but the wiki is so-so - not feature rich and it really doesn't have the option I need.

Additionally, I know someone out there will mention Drupal. I may consider it if I can see it put to use without and overabundance of custom programming (I don't mind initial coding, but drupal requires constant coding & recoding - with this site, I dont' have that time commitment)

I thought about using mediawiki with buddypress, but i'm not sure if that's the way to go.

Thoughts?

Comment: You may find Elgg http://elgg.org interesting

Comment: I have looked at Elgg, and I asked if it would be appropriate for my project, one of the developers responded that it was more social based, less content based. The content feature would not be powerful enough for my needs. Great suggestion all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A modified version of Mediawiki sounds like it could do everything you want to do. Mahalo.com does pretty much what you are talking about, and they (used to, I don't know if they do anymore) use a heavily modified version of Mediawiki.

Comment: I'll take a look more thoroughly at mediawiki and set up a testing environment for myself. Thanks for the input.